# Silverstripe 4 PaginatedList get Page-number - Link (Backlink)

Tags: pagination, position, silverstripe, data-objects

In Silverstripe 4 I have a

- DataObject 'PublicationObject',
- a 'PublicationPage' and
- a 'PublicationPageController'

PublicationObjects are displayed on PublicationPage through looping a PaginatedList. There is also a Pagination, showing the PageNumbers and Prev & Next - Links.

The Detail of PublicationObject is shown as 'Dataobject as Pages' using the UrlSegment.

If users are on the Detail- PublicationObject i want them to get back to the PublicationPage (the paginated list) with a **Back - Link**.

Two situations:

- The user came from PublicationPage

and

- The User came from a Search - Engine (Google) directly to the
  DataObject- Detail.

I have done this like so:

```
$parentPage = Page::get()->Filter(array('UrlSegment' => $request->param('pageID')))->First();
        
        $back = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))) {
            if (strtolower(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)) != strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
                // referer not from the same domain
                $back = $parentPage->Link();
            }
        }
```

Thats not satisfying.

**Question:**

How do i get the Pagination - Link ( e.g: ...publicationen?start=20 ) when we are on the Detail - DataObject? How can we find the Position of the current Dataobject in that paginatedList in correlation with the Items per Page? (The Page- Link This Dataobject is on)

```
<?php

use SilverStripe\Control\Controller;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest;
use SilverStripe\View\Requirements;
use SilverStripe\Core\Convert;
use SilverStripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig;
use SilverStripe\ORM\PaginatedList;
use SilverStripe\Control\Director;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\ErrorPage\ErrorPage;
use SilverStripe\Dev\Debug;
use SilverStripe\Dev\Backtrace;

class PublicationPageController extends PageController
{
    
    private static $allowed_actions = ['detail'];
    
    private static $url_handlers = array(
    );
    
    public static $current_Publication_id;
    
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
    
    public function detail(HTTPRequest $request)
    { 
        
        $publication = PublicationObject::get_by_url_segment(Convert::raw2sql($request->param('ID')));
        
        if (!$publication) {
            return ErrorPage::response_for(404);
        }
        
        
        
        // HERE I WANT TO FIND THE POSITION OF THE DATAOBJECT IN THE PAGINATEDLIST OR RATHER THE PAGE - LINK THIS DATAOBJECT IS IN
        //$paginatedList = $this->getPaginatedPublicationObjects();
        //Debug::show($paginatedList->find('URLSegment', Convert::raw2sql($request->param('ID'))));
        //Debug::show($paginatedList->toArray());
        
        
        $parentPage = Page::get()->Filter(array('UrlSegment' => $request->param('pageID')))->First();
        
        $back = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))) {
            if (strtolower(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)) != strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
                // referer not from the same domain
                $back = $parentPage->Link();
            }
        }
        
        static::$current_Publication_id = $publication->ID;
        $id = $publication->ID;
        
        if($publication){
            $arrayData = array (
                'Publication' => $publication,
                'Back' => $back,
                'SubTitle' => $publication->Title, 
                'MetaTitle' => $publication->Title, 
            );
                
            return $this->customise($arrayData)->renderWith(array('PublicationDetailPage', 'Page'));

        }else{
            return $this->httpError(404, "Not Found");
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public function getPaginatedPublicationObjects()
    {
        
        $list = $this->PublicationObjects()->sort('SortOrder');
        return  PaginatedList::create($list, $this->getRequest()); //->setPageLength(4)->setPaginationGetVar('start');
        
    }
    
}
```

**EDIT:**

is there a more simple solution ? than this ? :

```
public function detail(HTTPRequest $request)
    { 
        
        $publication = PublicationObject::get_by_url_segment(Convert::raw2sql($request->param('ID')));
        
        if (!$publication) {
            return ErrorPage::response_for(404);
        }
        
        //*******************************************************
        // CREATE BACK - LINK 
        $paginatedList = $this->getPaginatedPublicationObjects();
        $dO = PublicationObject::get();
        $paginationVar = $paginatedList->getPaginationGetVar();
        
        $sqlQuery = new SQLSelect();
        $sqlQuery->setFrom('PublicationObject');
        $sqlQuery->selectField('URLSegment');
        $sqlQuery->setOrderBy('SortOrder');
    
        $rawSQL = $sqlQuery->sql($parameters);

        $result = $sqlQuery->execute();
        $list = [];
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $list[]['URLSegment'] = $row['URLSegment'];
        }
        
        $list = array_chunk($list, $paginatedList->getPageLength(), true);
        $start = '';
        $back = '';
        $i = 0;
        $newArray = [];
        foreach ($list as $k => $subArr) {
            $newArray[$i] = $subArr;
            unset($subArr[$k]['URLSegment']);
            foreach ($newArray[$i] as $key => $val) {
                if ($val['URLSegment'] === Convert::raw2sql($request->param('ID'))) {
                    $start = '?'.$paginationVar.'='.$i;
                }
            }
            $i = $i + $paginatedList->getPageLength();
        }
        
        $back = Controller::join_links($this->Link(), $start);
        // END CREATE BACK - LINK
        //*****************************************************

        static::$current_Publication_id = $publication->ID;
        $id = $publication->ID;
        
        if($publication){
            $arrayData = array (
                'Publication' => $publication,
                'Back' => $back,
                'MyLinkMode' => 'active',
                'SubTitle' => $publication->Title, 
                'MetaTitle' => $publication->Title, 
            );
            return $this->customise($arrayData)->renderWith(array('PublicationDetailPage', 'Page'));
            
        }else{
            
            return $this->httpError(404, "Not Found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the page number as a get var in the URL from the `PublicationPage`. The `detail()` method can then grab the get var and if there's a value for the page number passed in, add it to the back link's URL.

In the template:

```html
<% loop $MyPaginatedList %>
    <a href="$Link?onPage=$Top.MyPaginatedList.CurrentPage">Click me</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

In your controller's `detail()` method:

```php
$pageNum = $request->getVar('onPage');
if ($pageNum) {
    // Add the pagenum to the back link here
}
```

### Edit

You've expressed that you want this to use the page start offset (so you can just plug it into the url using `?start=[offset]`), and that you want an example that also covers people coming in from outside your site. I therefore propose the following:

Do as above, but using `PageStart` instead of `CurrentPage` - this will mean you don't have to re-compute the offset any time someone clicks the link from your paginated list.

If there is no `onPage` (or `pageOffset` as I've renamed it below, assuming you'll use `PageStart`) get variable, then assuming you can ensure your `SortOrder` values are all unique, you can check how many items are in the list *before* the current item - which gives you your item offset. From that you can calculate what page it's on, and what the page offset is for that page, which is your `start` value.

```php
public function detail(HTTPRequest $request)
{ 
    $publication = PublicationObject::get_by_url_segment(Convert::raw2sql($request->param('ID')));
    $paginatedList = $this->getPaginatedPublicationObjects();

    // Back link logic starts here
    $pageOffset = $request->getVar('pageOffset');
    if ($pageOffset === null) {
        $recordOffset = $paginatedList->filter('SortOrder:LessThan', $publication->SortOrder)->count() + 1;
        $perPage = $paginatedList->getPageLength();
        $page = floor($recordOffset / $perPage) + 1;
        $pageOffset = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
    }
    $back = $this->Link() . '?' . $paginatedList->getPaginationGetVar() . '=' . $pageOffset;
    // Back link logic ends here
    //.....
}
```

Comment: $PageNum is a var in function PaginationSummary(). How do you get access to $PageNum in your <% loop $MyPaginatedList %> ? Also $PageNum returns Numbers like 1, 2, 3 ........9, 10, 11 and so on while i need something like ?start=9 what means e.g.  -- 3 Dataobjects per page  (depending on getPaginationGetVar())-- .... (3 x 3 = 9) ... so its the 3rd Page including Dataobject 7 and 8 and 9

Comment: I've updated my question -> // CREATE BACK - LINK ...... is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Apologies, I should have said `$CurrentPage` instead of `$PageNum` for the template. I've updated my example.

If you want the page offset instead of the page number, you can use `$FirstItem` or `$PageStart` instead.

Comment: also $CurrentPage is not satisfying. as i wrote, if the user comes from a search engine like Google directly to the detail page, the Get- vars (?onPage=$CurrentPage) are not present.

Comment: also $CurrentPage throws a Uncaught BadMethodCallException.......$CurrentPage.Link() returns the page-Link without "?start=9"

Comment: `$CurrentPage` called the `CurrentPage()` method on `PaginatedList`: https://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/ORM/PaginatedList.html#method_CurrentPage
It returns the current page number. You cannot call `Link()` on the result, because the result is an integer.

Comment: [Emergency] Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): the method 'forTemplate' does not exist on 'PublicationPageController' in your <% loop $MyPaginatedList %> ......(my function is called getPaginatedPublicationObjects()   .... but it does the same)

Comment: I have updated my example to account for your desire to use the offset and to capture the page offset even if you don't have it in the get var. I hope this helps.